# I have an email account from an ISP who only supports POP. Is there a way to get IMAP ability when the ISP does not support it?

Tags: imap, pop3

I want to be able to view an account's emails on a number of multiple devices but currently, if you view an email on one device it is removed from the email server so the other devices then do not see it. The ISP does not support IMAP so I cannot just change protocol on the account settings.

Maybe is there a way to forward the pop emails to an IMAP service? 
And if so, can the imap service reuse the same email address or not? (it would be nice to have but not critical)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your email client(s), you should be able to keep emails on the server when fetching them, even with POP3. You have to check the settings of the email client.

Depending on your ISP, you should be able to forward your email to another address. There are free email providers with IMAP support, see for example http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/features/email_providers.html.